# Passing value multiselect list to jquery function mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I'm having problems in passing values ​​to the function using jquery 
when I select the two dates as below:

[image]

This takes the values ​​that are in the text as shown, but I would take the values ​​and pass to the function below

```
var dtLev = $("#dateLev option:selected").text() 

$.getJSON("/Grafic/GetDateByGraf", { selectedRodId: rodId, selectLevId: levId, selectDtLev: dtLev},
```

If I use `.Val()` the null value appears

How can I fix this

Comment: **where** you use .val() ? **where** the value null appears ? **what** are you trying to do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543322/get-value-of-multiselect-box-using-jquery-or-javascript check this link

Comment: I posted the answer the way you got thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

got this way,

```
var selectedOptions = $.map($('#dateLev :selected'),
function (e) { return $(e).val(); });
var dtLev = selectedOptions.join(',');
```